# How to get payments connected with a certain transfer on Stripe through API?

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I have transfers that were related with payments. I can see those through dashboard but seems they are not available to get using the API.

[This is my charge on dashboard, as you can see it has two connected objects a customer and a transfer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5DTM.png)

[Transfer connected with many payments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJQ70.png)

Answer (score 1):

Once you have fetched a transfer you can use the transfer ID with the [balance transaction](https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#balance_transaction_object) method. It's the only parameter you need to pass and it will return all the transactions related to that transfer.

If you are using NodeJS for example then it would be:

```
stripe.balance.listTransactions({ transfer: 'tr_8ahwq8qw34n' })
```